# Unable to open file from sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, document-library

I have created a document library in my machine and uploaded a few image files. But later when i try to open them in document library, it shows a page not found 404 error. What could be the reason? The same thing works in another machine's document library

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of your image files? The IIS server will only return files with registered extentions, so if you are using a special type of imagefile you might need to register the mime type.

- ElinK

Comment: No, they are normal image files of jpg and png. It also cannot open word documents. Clicking every file throws a page not found error.